# more efficient way of working with YII? Querying the database

Tags: php, yii

This is a difficult question to ask as the code I have is working fine. Im just learning the YII platform and my issue isnt that I cant get what I want working, but moreso if there is a better way of doing this that takes advantage of the YII platform and its classes.

Basically I have a webstore using a platform called Lightspeed which uses the YII platform.

In the product detail section I am looking to pull its related products. Thankfully Lightspeed has the tables in place for this already (which gives me more reason to think I am doing this wrong).

Right now what Im doing seems a little hard coded.

In my view I have this to get the products...

```
$related_products = Product::GetRelatedProducts();
```

I have nothing in my controller, and in my model I have this..

```
    public function getRelatedProducts()
{
    $rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM xlsws_product as Product LEFT JOIN xlsws_product_related as ProductRelated ON ProductRelated.related_id=Product.id WHERE ProductRelated.related_id=Product.id ')->queryAll();

    return $rawData;
}
```

As I said there is nothing wrong with this code, but I see so much functionality in place with all the other queries in the model that it makes me think Im doing this incorrectly.

Examples include..

```
    protected function getSliderCriteria($autoadd=0)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->distinct = true;
    $criteria->alias = 'Product';
    $criteria->join='LEFT JOIN '.ProductRelated::model()->tableName().' as ProductRelated ON ProductRelated.related_id=Product.id';
    if (_xls_get_conf('INVENTORY_OUT_ALLOW_ADD',0)==Product::InventoryMakeDisappear)
        $criteria->condition = 'ProductRelated.product_id=:id AND inventory_avail>0 AND web=1 AND autoadd='.$autoadd.' AND parent IS NULL';
    else
        $criteria->condition = 'ProductRelated.product_id=:id AND web=1 AND autoadd='.$autoadd.' AND parent IS NULL';
    $criteria->params = array(':id'=>$this->id);
    $criteria->limit = _xls_get_conf('MAX_PRODUCTS_IN_SLIDER',64);
    $criteria->order = 'Product.id DESC';

    return $criteria;

}
```

Thats just an example of a widget that seems to use this data (although Im unsure how that data turns into arrays, as when I print out `$criteria` I get arrays containing query commands.

Let me know if you need more clarification on what Im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you're not leveraging Yii.  Yii (and other MVC frameworks), abstract the database layer out into a [model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.model).

The `getSliderCriteria()` you show above is an example of [building criteria](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/07/24/using-cdbcriteria-in-the-yii-framework/) to refine the interactions with the model.

What you should try and figure out is what model represents the data you're looking for in Lightspeed, then building and applying the criteria to it.

In most modern frameworks, you shouldn't be writing much (if any) raw SQL . . .